# Flow control based on integers in a field/column using Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have an enormous dataset that I need to clean up but I'm not sure how to use flow control to get the output I need. Column A is an integer that can be any number. I'm interested in when there are specific numbers (0, 00, 000, or nothing) in column A. If these exist, I want to C to contain A. If they dont exist, I want C to be B + '-'+ A

Input Table

```
A     B    C
0     1   
00    2 
      3 
000   4 
4     5 
10    6
```

My shot at code

```
if A = 0, 00, 000, null:
    write B
else:
    Write B + "-" +  A
```

Desired Output (Column C)

```
A     B    C
0     1    1
00    2    2
      3    3
000   4    4
4     5    5-4
10    6    6-10
```

Comment: Is your data in a Pandas DataFrame? What have you tried, exactly? Can you share at least part of the dataset? I also disagree that the values in `A` should be treated as integers.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile My data is not in a pandas dataframe. It's spatial data, so its in a geodatabase. I just realized that Column a sometimes has letters in it, so it cant be an integer. You are right.

Comment: Can you share the code that creates/reads the data? Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is tab-separated, a solution could look similar to the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io 

data =  """A    B
0   1
00  2
    3
000 4
4   5
10  6"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\t', dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
blacklist = ['0','00','000', '']
df['C'] = np.where(np.isin(df['A'], blacklist), df['B'], df['B']+'-'+df['A'])
print(df)
```

Output

```
     A  B     C
0    0  1     1
1   00  2     2
2       3     3
3  000  4     4
4    4  5   5-4
5   10  6  6-10
```